# Undefined class OneSignal

Tags: laravel, onesignal

I use Laravel 5.2 and want to use berkayk/laravel-onesignal package, and I installed this package step by step according to Guide on [github](https://github.com/berkayk/laravel-onesignal).

But when I want to use this package I get "Undefined class OneSignal", also I run this artisan command in the terminal:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

I try this code in controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use OneSignal;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SignalController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        OneSignal::sendNotificationToAll("Some Message");
    }
}
```

[I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yj4D.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use full namespace for the facade:

```
\OneSignal::sendNotificationToAll("Some Message");
```

Or add this to the top of your class:

```
use OneSignal;
```

Comment: I do this but don't work, i use phpStorm and add uses dynamically, OneSignal class does not recognize

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My reputation under 15 and can't vote to this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should write `use OneSignal` top of the class underneath the namespace.

Hope this work for you!

Comment: I hope you follow all the steps given at you used [laravel-onesignal](https://github.com/berkayk/laravel-onesignal)
. Specially *Aftwards, run `composer update` from your command line*